# Always get NULL when getting the selected value from dropdown Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the selected value from a dropdown in my view through my controller, but it's always returning `null`. I really don't know why.

Here is my select dropdown:
UPDATED: Here is my full blade view!

```html
@extends('backpack::layout')

@section('header')
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            <span class="text-capitalize">Thành tích tốt nhất ngày</span>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="/admin/dashboard">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/cache-club-earth">Thành tích tốt nhất ngày</a></li>
            <li class="active">List</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <form method="GET">
        Lọc round:
            <select id="tablefilter" name="tablefilter">
            <option value="0">Hiện tại</option>
    
            @foreach($max as $item)
                <option value="{{$item->countRound}}">{{$item->countRound}}</option>
            @endforeach
    
        </select>
    </form>
    

    <table id="currentRound" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Câu lạc bộ</th>
                <th>Quãng đường</th>
                <th>Quãng đường trung bình</th>
                <th>Xếp hạng</th>
                <th>Số thành viên</th>
                <th>Ngày xếp hạng</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($result as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
                <td align="right">{{number_format($item->total_distance/1000, 2)}} km</td>
                <td align="right">{{number_format($item->avg_distance/1000, 2)}} km</td>
                <td align="right">{{number_format($item->rank)}}</td>
                <td align="right">{{$item->total_member}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#currentRound').DataTable({
            "paging" : true,
            "aaSorting": [[3, 'asc']],
            "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        });
    });

    </script>
@endsection

@section('after_styles')
    <!-- DATA TABLES -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!-- CRUD LIST CONTENT - crud_list_styles stack -->
    @stack('crud_list_styles')
@endsection

@section('after_scripts')

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
            src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
            src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@endsection
```

And in my controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request) {

    $round = $request->input('tablefilter');

    //dd($round);

    $mMile = new MilestoneEarth();

    $max = $mMile->getRound();

    return view('admin.cacheClubEarth.index',['result' => $result, 'max' => $max]);

}
```

It's return [] with $request->all() and null with $request->tablefilter

I really don't know how to do with this!

Can you help me!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please update complete code of controller and form?

Comment: Try with `$request->tablefilter`.

Comment: I don't have form, I just have a select dropdown in my view and I just trying to get its value in controller.

Comment: it's still null with $request->tablefilter

Comment: If you are not submitting a form then who you are providing the value of select to request parameter?
How you are making the call to the back-end? Ajax or redirect by link?

Comment: what if `dd($request);` ?

Comment: So how you are calling the controller 'index' on change of dropdown? if you don't have form

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. So how I can fix this? I tried to add a form tag: <form method="GET"> //my select dropdown </form> but it's still null when I tried to get its value

Comment: $round = $request->input('tablefilter');  its meaning less dear. how could you call data from database and show on view. where is model ?

Comment: in my model, I just have a query function which return data to use in controller.

Comment: $max ? from where?

Comment: I edited my post. It's contain my query function data in model

Answer (score 0):

You can do : dd(request->all()); for check the data.
I think you don't have to use the input function. Try this :

```
$round = $request->tablefilter;
```

Comment: it's return [] with $request->all() and null with $request->tablefilter

Comment: @Tomato Can you show me the blade complete form ?
It's the good controller called ?

Comment: Ok i found the problem.

First thing, i hope your route isn't this : {{url('/to/index/controller/you-want')}}
But i think you just change it for the demonstration

You can't get a GET paremters with $request i think.

$request->tablefilter is when your tablefilter parameter is send by POST Request.

You can get the parameter like this for GET parameter:
$round = $_GET['tablefilter'];

Comment: Well my route is Route::get('/', 'CacheClubEarthController@index'); and I got error when I change to $_GET['tablefilter']: "Undefined index: tablefilter"

Comment: <form method="GET" action="{{url('/to/index/controller/you-want')}}>

You have this ? You should change the URL

Comment: Is this action="url('/')" same to my route?

Comment: If your route have a name like this :
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->name('profile');

You can generate the link with the name of the route like this :
{{ route('profile') }}

If she don't have any name. You should enter your URL manually like this :
{{ url('user/profile') }}

It's ok for you ?

Comment: it's look ok now, when I choose an item, my url be /cache-club-earth?tablefilter=1. But in my controller, $round = $request->tablefilter still cannot get the tablefilter value

Comment: <form method="GET" action="{{url('/to/index/controller/you-want')}}>

Cause you have the get method
You should use $_GET['tablefilter'];

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the form value either submit using button or use ajax for it

here the basic submitting data via form (i specified action in case you go to different page)

```
    <form method="GET" action="{{url('/to/index/controller/you-want')}}>
        Lọc round:
            <select id="tablefilter" name="tablefilter">
                <option value="0">Hiện tại</option>

                @foreach($max as $item)
                     <option value="{{$item->countRound}}">{{$item->countRound}}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>
            <button class="something">Update</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: And in my controller I used $request -> get('tablefilter') but still null, so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($max as $item)
     <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: I just want to get only countRound in my $item

Comment: my problem is I can't get the value of dropdown

Comment: i think you have to change logic from your controller. all problem occure from their. please kindly check all code and their referance variable are correct or not.

Comment: check one by one  is dd($round); is worked or not. if not so you have to change this line.